# This code redirects to login page instead of staying in same home page.

Tags: php, session, cookies, xampp, session-cookies

I want my website to be accessed either by session or cookie. But after writing this code, the page needs both condition to be true instead of one. 
What's wrong here?

```
<?php
    if(((isset($_SESSION['SUCCESS']) && $_SESSION['SUCCESS'] != "") || 
    (isset($_COOKIE['is_logged_in']) && $_COOKIE['is_logged_in'] != "")) 
     == false){
        $_SESSION['ERROR'] = "Please login first";
        header('location: login.php'); 
    }

?>
```

Comment: try to split it into an `if..else if..` and test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['is_logged_in']) && $_COOKIE['is_logged_in'] != ""){
    if(!isset($_SESSION['SUCCESS'])){
        $_SESSION['SUCCESS'] = true;//or whatever you want
    }
}
```

And then check session

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['SUCCESS']) || $_SESSION['SUCCESS'] == ""){
    $_SESSION['ERROR'] = "Please login first";
    header('location: login.php');
}else{
    //move to home page
}
```

Comment: while trying to login, if i don't check on "remember me", it won't give me access to home page. So this means that without using cookie i wouldn't be able to login.

Comment: why is code which I put earlier not working for you? It's working for me.

Comment: i am using this code in login page. May be its because of this:

if( (isset($_SESSION['SUCCESS']) && $_SESSION['SUCCESS'] != "") || (isset($_COOKIE['is_logged_in']) && $_COOKIE['is_logged_in'] != "")) {
        header('location: index.php');

    }

Answer (score 0):

No need to write `== false`. Try with removing it

```
if((isset($_SESSION['SUCCESS']) && $_SESSION['SUCCESS'] != "") || 
(isset($_COOKIE['is_logged_in']) && $_COOKIE['is_logged_in'] != "")
 ){
    $_SESSION['ERROR'] = "Please login first";
    header('location: login.php'); 
}
```

Comment: this will give direct access to the home page without doing login.